# How do I track User IDs w/Google Analytics & no page reload after login?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

We have an angular project that we want to track User IDs with Google Analytics.

The problem is, when the user is logged out & first loads the site, we have the create call pass "auto"

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

When the user logs in, there is no page load. Is it a problem to call the "create" event again with the User ID, or is there a better way to do this?

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the set method if the user logs in after page load

```
ga('set', 'userId', 'USERID');
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#user