# Edit analytics tracker configuration

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to be able to edit my tracker configuration after the user has logged in to my site.
My scenario:
1) When site is loaded I initialise my tracker.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

2) I send tracking events for user action before he logs in.

3) User logs in.
- Here I want to be able to edit the tracker to include the userId of the logged-in user,
 for all subsequent events.
can I make another call to create, something like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', { 'userId': 'USER_ID' });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367237/how-do-i-track-user-ids-w-google-analytics-no-page-reload-after-login

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) for this. An example using a JS object for the user info:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
if(user) {
  ga('dimension1', user.id);
}
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Just note that capturing any user-identifiable information is against Google's ToS.